# Updating cocoapods to swift 3

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift3, xcode8

I tried `pod spec lint`

```
[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 14 errors.
```

it seems like it is trying to build for older version of swift.

I also added .swift-version with text 3.0 still the same effect

All the code is done and updated in git.

Comment: can you show your Podfile?

Comment: in example app or the pod spec?

Comment: sry I've misunderstood you, I think. So you have problems with updating cocoapods to the newest version, thought you want to load dependencies for your project. Maybe this will help you http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation, if you not already used it

Comment: No I am having trouble in updating the pod spec even though I have updated to swift 3 still users are not getting the latest one.